# Inserting objects with oracle dbms

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle

I'm trying to solve this:

A user class with 50 fields is defined in .NET. I need to insert this fields in one table. Instance fields are same as table fields. Does Oracle have some type or something else like .NET object?

For example: Define an object in oracle, define stored procedure to insert object in table, call sp in .NET, pass instance with 50 fields to procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to look into the [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386876.aspx) kit for Oracle [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/oracleefbeta-302521.html)

Comment: +1, good answer, but esp because Windman will probably not give credit ;)